# Mouse wait to click action

Tags: c#, mouseevent, mouse

How I can mouse wait on the button for one second to select this button ?
I have 5 button and when the user want to select one of them must wait for 1 second to select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any built in method. You need to figure Your own solution - there are few i Think. For exmaple: Make this buttons disabled at start and use MouseEnter Event to enable it after one second(1000 milisecond).

```
MouseEnter_handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button MyButton = sender as Button;
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
    sw.Start();
    while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000)
    {}
    MyButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

Bind this method to all buttons, since there is a sender parameter - You don't need to copy that all the time.

Comment: BTW. In the while loop You can also add a condition which will check if cursor is still above the button if You need it.